# Compute $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{3}{(3 k)!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

These days I came across this series and I'm trying to figure out how to compute it

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{3}{(3 k)!}$$

I thought to combine some elementary functions, but it doesn't work. Some hints, suggestions?

Comment: but... but... $3/3k=1/k$

Comment: That's true, @vakufo , yet $\,3/3k\,$ is *not* what is written in that sum....

Comment: Oh my god, I see it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\omega$ be a complex cube root of 1. Think about $$e^{\omega x}+e^{\omega^2x}+e^x$$

Comment: I didn't think of that

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}=e$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{(3k)!}+\frac{1}{(3k+1)!}+\frac{1}{(3k+2)!}\right]$$

Comment: hmmm, interesting trick